# Automatically convert string to the right numerical type

Tags: python, string

I was wondering if there's an elegant and easy way to convert a string (that I know can be converted to a number) to the corresponding numerical type. For example, if my string represents an integer, I want the value converted to `int`; same for `long`, `float`, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `ast.literal_eval`.

```
import ast

examples = ["1", "1.5", "999999999999999999999999999999999999999999", "23+42j"]
for item in examples:
    result = ast.literal_eval(item)
    print result
    print type(result)
```

Result:

```
1
<type 'int'>
1.5
<type 'float'>
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
<type 'long'>
(23+42j)
<type 'complex'>
```

Comment: also for complex numbers :)

Comment: @marmeladze, true. I'll add an example.

Comment: A note from the `ast.literal_eval` docs for anyone like me who has never seen this before and is worried about security: "This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources"